#  Encoding of sent data not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, encoding

I've got a little chatbox, everything's working, except for sending special latin chars like äöü.

This is the post which sends the input, as soon enter is pressed (it's placed in the body, not in the header, couldn't figure out how to put it in the header --> vBulletin Template):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#shout").keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "http://example.com/api.php",
        contentType: "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1",
        data: {
          action: "shout",
          // This is what I found on the internet to
          // encode the data, but didn't help.
          message: $('<div />').text($("#shout").val()).html()
        },
        success: function() {
          $("#shout").val("");
        }
      })
    }
  });
</script>
```

**On the server side**

```
// Insert shout
case "shout":
if(isset($_GET['message']) && $_GET['message'] != "") {
  $mc->insertShout($userid, mktime(), $_GET['message']);
}

break;
```

**insertShout logic**

```
public function insertShout($userid, $date, $message, $notification = 0) {
  $sql = "INSERT INTO
  vb_chatbox_shout (userid, dateline, message, message_raw, notification)
        VALUES
          (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

  $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);

  $stmt->bindParam(1, $userid);
  $stmt->bindParam(2, $date);
  $stmt->bindParam(3, $message);
  $stmt->bindParam(4, $message);
  $stmt->bindParam(5, $notification);

  if(!$stmt->execute()) {
    var_dump($stmt->errorInfo());
  }

  return 1;
}
```

I've tried using utf-8 as charset, but no luck. Also, post didn't help. Using this kind of ajax to pull the chatbox content works like a charm (special chars directly inserted to db with phpmyadmin are showed correctly).

The problem is not in inserting the chars to the database. When I dump the $_GET var at the first entry point, it's already messed up, so the problem's between jQuery and PHP.

**New headers**

```
GET /api.php?action=shout&message=%25C3%25B6%25C3%25A4%25C3%25BC HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Connection: keep-alive
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.52 Safari/536.5
Accept: */*
Referer: http://example.com/forum/forum.php
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: de
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: skimlinks_enabled=1; bb_lastvisit=1316066700; bb_lastactivity=0; bb_userid=1;


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 28 May 2012 17:26:14 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.9
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Comment: what is the point of:   contentType: "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" ?

Comment: Why not, I just tried around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace

```
message: $('<div />').text($("#shout").val()).html()
```

with

```
message: encodeURIComponent($('<div />').text($("#shout").val()).html())
```

in javascript, and then replace

```
$mc->insertShout($userid, mktime(), $_GET['message']);
```

with

```
$mc->insertShout($userid, mktime(), urldecode($_GET['message']));
```

and add

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

at the beginning of PHP file.

if `urldecode` at php doesn't work, try replacing it with `rawurldecode()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but neither one of both decoders changed something.

Comment: did you remove the contenttype definition of yours?

Comment: how's your data posted now? can you give a POST data example here?

Comment: It's not POST, it's GET, I just tested POST once, to see if it makes a difference. HTTP Headers added in question.

Comment: it should give `%25%C3%25%B6%25%C3%25%A4%25%C3%25%BC` instead of `%25C3%25B6%25C3%25A4%25C3%25BC`.

Comment: change encodeURIComponent to encodeURI and tell me what happens.

Comment: where does that `Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1` come from? the headers are the same btw. Remove one of them.

Comment: the html is properly utf8 also? eg.  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> or <meta charset='utf8'> ?

Comment: Well, I checked again, and I can't see latin encoding in the php file or in the javascript (at least in the parts required to post a shout). The other parts, used to display the data are LATIN.

Comment: vBulletin itself uses <meta charset="ISO-8859-1" />. I've made an iframe containing the chatbox which gets it's header set by PHP "header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');" to output the data. The part inserting the data, is utf-8 as you specified though. I'll try changing everything to utf-8. But as I said in the question, displaying special chars works when they have been inserted trough an direct SQL query. The data is already wrong encoded when it's coming from jQuery, PHP than just inserts it.

Comment: i dont know about vBulletin but is there a path (Admin CP -> Languages & Phrases -> Language Manager -> [Edit Settings] -> HTML Character Set) to change character set? i dont know the risk anyway of messing with this..

Comment: Ok, I have to use ISO-8859-1, otherwise my default chatbox get's messed up. I tried changing everything to utf-8 (except vBulletin itself), and posting from my chatbox worked. Unfortunately, everything what has been posted trough the default chatbox by vbulletin, looks messed up when it is viewed by my chatbox. This effect is vice versa (that means, something posted by my own chatbox is displayed properly, as long as i view it from my chatbox. As soon as i change to the default chatbox, everything coming from my chatbox is messed up). I now changed every charset to ISO-8859-1, but still errors

Comment: Btw, I tried changing the charset in the Admin CP to utf-8, and it messed up everything. I have to stick with LATIN